# From Spritebuilder to Xcode CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, spritebuilder

I have a Question, 
I added an CCSprite with Image, now I want to work on this CCSprite in XCode, but I don't know how can I link it?
Yeah I know thats, a easy question, but not for me, 
Can you help me?
Have I used a Custom Class name?

[image: Set Doc Vat]

[image: Call CCSprite]

Comment: Are you trying to subclass ccsprite or using ccsprite as is without subclassing?

Comment: for each ccSprite create a subclass? ,

Comment: I created a subclass, but i can't change anything, like color or so

Comment: Not needed. If you want to add more functionality then subclass, else just add sprite to the node, give a name to it in docrootvar and in Xcode use (CCSprite*)[self getChildByName:@"spritename" recursively:YES] on the node in which you added the sprite to get a reference.

Comment: Nothing happen, I uploaded my steps, maybe i did something wrong, I tried to change the color, but If i tested, it is still white.

Comment: use -(void)didLoadFromCCB instead of -(id)init.

Comment: hmm, okay, anything I will do wrong, again nothing happen...
I got an error message on Console.
2014-12-25 08:24:16.346 test[41943:739434] CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable: ball1
2014-12-25 08:24:16.347 test[41943:739434] CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable: ball2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67659/discussion-between-johnny-peter-and-j0k3r).

Answer (score 0):

In the example above you have set a member variable, and not the name property of the sprite.

You can either create a `CCSprite* ball1;` member variable in your header file or set the name property of the sprite and use your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I have to set a Name of this CCSprite not a "Doc root var" or Custom Class.
That was, what I had to do.
No it is still working.
But Thanks all for helping

[image: Add Name]